# Issue with entire table being clickable instead of a single row within a WEBGRID

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have changed my application to incorporate a frontend changes. I have now created tables and within these tables, i have @RenderBody()

When my webgrid shows upon my screen, the entire screen becomes clickable instead of just the individual rows within the WEBGRID.

Here is the _InitLayout, which is used. Refer to the RenderBody() part,. Its called inside a table.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>                  
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />      

    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png"  href='@Url.Content("~/Content/favicon.png")' />

    </head>

    <body>
            <div onload="MM_preloadImages('@Url.Content("~/Content/images/buttons/signup2.jpg")','@Url.Content("~/Content/images/buttons/logon2.jpg")'">
                <table width="980" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                    <td class="tdfrontend" colspan="2"><img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/interface/header.jpg")' alt="header" width="1000" height="105" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="tdfrontend" colspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <table width="1000" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="tdfrontend">
                        <table width="1000" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                          <tr>
                            <td class="tdfrontend" width="700">
                            <table width="365" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td class="tdfrontend" width="18" align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td class="tdfrontend" align="center" valign="middle"><span class="style3"><a href="/" style="text-decoration:none">Home</a></span>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td class="tdfrontend" align="center" valign="middle"><img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/interface/lineup.jpg")' alt="linup" width="3" height="22" /></td>
                                <td class="tdfrontend" align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;<span class="style3">@Html.ActionLink("Browse All Projects", "AllProjectsHeaderSR", "Projects", "",new { @style = "text-decoration:none" } )</span>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td class="tdfrontend" align="center" valign="middle"><img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/interface/lineup.jpg")' alt="linup" width="3" height="22" /></td>
                                <td class="tdfrontend" align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;<span class="style3">@Html.ActionLink("Search Projects", "SearchProjectsSR", "Projects", "",new { @style = "text-decoration:none" })</span>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td class="tdfrontend" align="center" valign="middle"><img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/interface/lineup.jpg")' alt="linup" width="3" height="22" /></td>
                                <td class="tdfrontend" align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;<span class="style3">@Html.ActionLink("How It Works", "HowItWorks", "Home", "",new { @style = "text-decoration:none" })</span>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td class="tdfrontend" align="center" valign="middle"><img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/interface/lineup.jpg")' alt="linup" width="3" height="22" /></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table></td>
                            <td class="tdfrontend" width="300" align="right" valign="middle">
                            <table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td class="tdfrontend" width="221" align="right"><a href="@Url.Action("LogOn","Account")" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('logon','','@Url.Content("~/Content/images/buttons/logon2.jpg")',1)"><img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/buttons/logon1.jpg")' name="logon" width="80" height="19" border="0" id="logon" /></a></td>
                                <td class="tdfrontend" width="79" align="right"><a href="@Url.Action("Register", "Account")" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('signup','','@Url.Content("~/Content/images/buttons/signup2.jpg")',1)"><img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/buttons/signup1.jpg")' name="signup" width="79" height="19" border="0" id="signup" /></a></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="tdfrontend" colspan="2" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/interface/line.jpg")' alt="ling" width="1000" height="4" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  </table>
            </div>   

        <div id="container">
            <div id="col1"> 
                @RenderSection("SideBar1", required: false)
            </div> 
            <div id="col2outer1"> 
                <div id="col2mid1">                    
                  <table width="980" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="tdfrontend" width="600" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                            @RenderBody()
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
                    <table width="600" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdfrontend" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="tdfrontend">
                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="tdfrontend" height="150" align="center" valign="middle"><img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/pics/it_pic1.jpg")' alt="it pic1" width="96" height="100" /></td>
                          <td class="tdfrontend" align="center" valign="middle"><img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/pics/it_pic2.jpg")' alt="it pic2" width="158" height="100" /></td>
                          <td class="tdfrontend" align="center" valign="middle"><img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/pics/it_pic3.jpg")' alt="it pic 3" width="157" height="100" /></td>
                          <td class="tdfrontend" align="center" valign="middle"><img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/pics/it_pic4.jpg")' alt="it pic 4" width="131" height="100" /></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                   </table>
                   </td>

                <td class="tdfrontend" width="400" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tdfrontend"><img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/interface/blu_header.jpg")' alt="blu_header" width="400" height="34" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tdfrontend" align="left" valign="top" background='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/interface/blu_bg.jpg")'><table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="15" cellpadding="3">
                            <tr>
                            <td class="tdfrontend"><p>populate info hieght controlled </p>
                                <p>populate info hieght controlled </p>
                                <p>populate info hieght controlled </p>
                                <p>populate info hieght controlled </p>
                                <p>populate info hieght controlled </p>
                                <p>populate info hieght controlled </p>
                                <p>populate info hieght controlled </p>
                                <p>populate info hieght controlled </p>
                                <p>populate info hieght controlled </p>
                                <p>populate info hieght controlled </p>
                                <p>populate info hieght controlled </p>
                                <p>populate info hieght controlled </p>
                                <p>populate info hieght controlled </p>
                                <p>populate info hieght controlled </p>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tdfrontend"><img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/interface/blu_footer.png")' alt="blu_footer" width="400" height="23" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td class="tdfrontend" colspan="2" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#1780BA">
                <table width="980" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
                    <tr>
                    <td class="tdfrontend" width="100" class="news"><span class="footer_text">&copy; Copyright 2012 GrepTech.co.za</span></td>
                    <td class="tdfrontend" width="466" align="right" valign="middle" class="footer_text">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Privacy Policy", "PrivacyPolicy", "Home", "", new { style = "color:#FFFFFF", target = "_blank" }) 
                        &nbsp; 
                        &nbsp; 
                        @Html.ActionLink("Terms & Conditions", "TermsConditions", "Home", "", new { style = "color:#FFFFFF", target = "_blank" })    
                        &nbsp; 
                        &nbsp;
                        @Html.ActionLink("Advertise", "Advertise", "Home", "", new { style = "color:#FFFFFF" })
                        &nbsp;
                        &nbsp;
                        @Html.ActionLink("Contact Us", "ContactUs", "Home", "", new { style = "color:#FFFFFF", target = "_blank" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>

            </div>
            <div id="col2side1"> 
                @RenderSection("SideBar2", required: false) 
            </div> 
         </div>
            <br />
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is my VIEW for the WEBGRID:

```
    @model mvc1.Models.ProjectHeaderModelList 

    @{ 
        if (ViewBag.userTypeID == null) 
        { 
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_InitLayout.cshtml"; 

        } 
        else if (ViewBag.userTypeID == "SP") 
        { 
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SPLayout.cshtml";              
        } 
        else if (ViewBag.userTypeID == "SR") 
        { 
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SRLayout.cshtml";              
        } 
    } 

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 

    @{ 
        ViewBag.Title = "All Projects"; 
    } 

    @section SideBar1 { 
                        <p> 
                        </p> 
    } 

    @section SideBar2 { 
                                <p> 
                                </p>  

    } 

    @{ 
        if (ViewBag.userName != null) 
        { 
            <div align="right"><font color="#000000" size="2">User: @ViewBag.userName  is logged in</font></div> 
        } 
    }             

    @{ 
        if (ViewBag.Message != null) 
        { 
            <p><font color="red">@ViewBag.Message </font></p> 
        } 
    } 

    @{ 
        var grid = new WebGrid(Model, 
                               rowsPerPage: 5, 
                               defaultSort: "projectStatus"); 
    } 

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    { 
        if (ViewBag.userName != null) 
        { 
            <br /> 
        } 

        if (ViewBag.userTypeID == null) 
        { 
            <br /> 
            <p> @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") to GrepTech or @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account") if you don't have an account. 
            </p> 
        } 

    <fieldset> 
      <legend>List Of All Projects</legend> 
      <br /> 
    <div id="grid"> 

        @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns( 
                        grid.Column("projectCode", "Project Code", canSort: true), 
                        grid.Column("projectName", "Project Name", canSort: true), 
                        grid.Column("projectCreationDate", header: "Created Date", format: @<text>@item.projectCreationDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")</text>, canSort: true), 
                        grid.Column("projectEndDate", header: "Bidding Expiry Date", format: @<text>@item.projectEndDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")</text>, canSort: true), 
                        grid.Column("projectStatus", "Project Status", canSort: true), 
                        grid.Column("daysLeft", "Days Remaining", canSort: true)), 
            tableStyle: "webgrid", 
            headerStyle: "webgrid-header", 
            footerStyle: "webgrid-footer", 
            selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row", 
            rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style")     
    </div>   

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function () { 
            $('tbody tr').on('hover', function () { 
                $(this).toggleClass('clickable'); 
            }).on('click', function () { 
                var self = this; 
                $.ajax( 
                            { 
                                type: "POST", 
                                url: "/Projects/AllProjectsHeaderSR", 
                                data: "projectCode=" + $(this).find('td:first').text(), 
                                success: function (data) { 
                                    $('#container').html(data); 
                                    $(self).unbind('click'); 
                                } 
                            }); 
            }); 
        });  
    </script>  
    </fieldset> 
    }
```

As you can see the clickable part is set in the Jquery for the VIEW(). But the entire screen becomes clickable. Im guessing because the RenderBody() is within tables ? Im not sure.

How do i go about just getting the row clickable within the webgrid only ?

SOLUTION:

Changed :

```
$('tbody tr').on('hover', function () {
```

TO:

```
$('#grid tbody tr').on('hover', function () {
```

Comment: pls remove the commented code.

Comment: Done .. Can you tell me how to make this work ?

Comment: managed to get solution .. the solution is at the end of the question

Comment: @NarenGokal it's great that you have found the solution for your problem, but to help future visitors please add the solution as an answer to your question (and mark it accepted) instead of editing it inside your question.